# is there any way to GET the application icon badge number?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

While it is not possible to access the notifications - just to make sure is there any way to GET the application icon badge number?

Setting is like this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:n];
```

All I need is a `getApplicationIconBadgeNumber` - is there really no access to the current number from within the app?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use the applicationIconBadgeNumber property of UIApplication.

The getter is the same as the property name while the setter has the prefix 'set'.

Comment: super thank you very much - I was looking for get... method! Amazing that it did not show up in Google when I typed "get application icon bagde number" anywhere!